# 'module' object has no attribute Error Using Python 2.7.11 Notepad++ PyNPP on Windows 8.1

Tags: python, object, module, attributes, notepad++

I'm getting 'module' object has no attribute error whenever I am trying to run my Python scripts on Notepad++, I've tried using just Run command and I got the same error.

I've followed a reductionist approach and written two line code to narrow down the problem. I've tested the code on native IDLE and Notepad++. IDLE runs the script perfectly where as Notepad++ throws an error.

I've checked pathways, installations, even UTF encodings and there is not a single problem. Code is given below, and in order not to have a problem it is taken from Python.org itself.

I've searched the web but I could not find an answer, those who had problems generally had typos in their code however I've tested my code for typos and reduced it to a state just to show error and cross validated using native IDLE.

```
import random
A = random.randint(1, 10)
```

Comment: In short: you probably have another file named either `random.py` or `random.pyc`.

Comment: **Alternative**: using NppExec plugin with command `python "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` and be sure to check the option `Follow $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)` in *Plugins > NppExec*.